# How to configure NSB to send Error-logs to Windows event viewer?

Tags: windows, nservicebus

I need to be able to check for errors on NSB in Windows Application Event Log. Mainly for Errors, but also warnings would be useful.

I get:
Errors on NSB is showing up in "Server Manager" \ Features \ Message Queuing \ Private Queues \ Errors

I Want:
Errors on NSB is showing up in "Server Manager" \ Diagnostics \ Event Viewer \ Application and Service Logs

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a EventLogAppender (or similar) to your configuration and use your logging framework to create the entries when exception occurs using the appropriate levels. Be sure no to actually handle the exception, just catch and log (and rethrow).